# Finding distribution of a set of numbers

Tags: excel, numbers, visualization

I have a set of numbers and want to see the distribution of points(in what range do the points fall).Is there any good software or piece of code that can do this?
I just want to see in what range does the major chunk lie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in function FREQUENCY

Form excel help:

```
Calculates how often values occur within a range of values, and then returns a vertical 
array of numbers. For example, use FREQUENCY to count the number of test scores that
fall within ranges of scores. Because FREQUENCY returns an array, it must be entered 
as an array formula.
```